# how to two way bind angular-ui-bootstrap-modal without watches and services

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, controllers, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am implementing the Angular ui bootstrap modal from
**[angular-ui-modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)**

The basic design exemplified  by them is on the plunker next to it.

However my application requires it(the modal) to be implemented multiple times in the same single page web application (for saving loading etc).

In this plunker have modified their basic plunker **[link : [see my plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntqx6VYLJYepKbM2YaZZ?p=preview)]**

In the above plunker I am trying to apply dynamic binding between two controllers.
as in :

**I want the value of "checkBind" from the inner controller modal template to be reflected in outer controller.**

I know this is not possible like i am trying to do it because the "scopes are different".

Now i am not so convinced for using watches / broadcast /services for this
"petty modal  thing".

**I have few questions :**

1. Do I have to create a separate controller for using the angular ui modal.
2. How can i use the "OuterCtrl"(in my plunker) to somehow write all the modal invoking and handler methods(like $scope.open.... $scope.ok .... $scope.cancel etc).
3. how can I directly bind the value of checkBind from the modal to the outerController in the least code possible(i mean by ignoring the watches services etc)

**If "3" is possible then I can really ignore 1 and 2 (but i would still want to know the answer)**

I know I am missing something here. Please tell me what is that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I am new to angular and your english is a bit difficult to follow, but can't you instead set it to `modal.checkBind` and then put that property in a higher scope?

Comment: are you saying this. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUTyi5Vyl6tKB2SratlF?p=preview). still not working

Comment: did you try $broadcast / $on

Comment: i understand that its possible using that. but my issue is that for something petty like a modal it would be verbose to have a seperate controller in the first place and then using the value entered in the modal( input box ) and broadcast it to the main controller . And all this for what ..... getting the name of the "save as" file

Comment: oh, it doesn't work because you never intialized $scope.modal = {}. did you ever get thiss working? it's pretty simple

Comment: can you fiddle it if possible. that would be a lot of help.